# no command line argument

Tags: java, command-line, netbeans

I have asked about `how to use command line argument in netbeans` in stackoverflow and they tell me to read this [article](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html) and also I read its comments but when i run this program it will return "no command line argument" and I don't know what should I do? please guide me more about it.thanks

also one comment in that article is :

> You may have had the same problem that I had...
>
> The path to your run-time command line args is stored in the netbeans private.properties file as
>
> ```
> "application.args=".
> ```
>
> You may have overridden your private.properties file with an entry in your build.xml of
>
> ```
> target name="-init-private" depends="-pre-init"
> ```
>
> If you have, then args[] won't get picked up at runtime unless you create an overriding entry in your project.properties file to replace the one that should be picked up from your private.properties.

And I couldn't get what he mean ,please guide me step by step because really I am beginner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [command line arguments.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301557/command-line-arguments)

Comment: Can you please add an example of the command line you use to start your java program ?

Comment: @ org.life.java,I said it that I have asked such a this question but it is something different from that subject why it is duplicate?

Comment: @ Riduidel,I use exactly the example in the article that I have put its link in the above and I use "One Two Three" as command line arguments.

Comment: @user472221 Create a new java project and do the same for that, there might be some change done by mistake in conf. I guess .

Comment: i have done it several times but it prints "no command line arguments" again !!! :(((

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the arguments to the run dialog box as shown in the screenshot?

[image]